# external displays receive input signals ONLY when I open a Powerpoint file and use slide show mode?

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint

At work I use two external displays as extended monitors. Today suddenly I lost my input signals to both external displays.

Strangely, when I opened a Powerpoint file and read the slides in a slide mode, the slides were projected to the third display (which has an "in-slide" control panel to move forward and backward the slides) while the second display is considered "co-display" with the laptop monitor (as indicated by 1|2, and 3, when I tried to identify the displays).

What happens to the two external displays so that Powerpoint slide mode can project signals to the two external displays but when I close the Powerpoint file I would lose the input signals to the two external monitors.

And how can I resolve the issue of "no input signal" to the two external displays when I close Powerpoint program?

Comment: Is PowerPoint configured to use a specific resolution on said display... and is it that resolution which is needed for the display to show content?

Comment: not sure. I assume it is configured in the default setting. Both PowerPoint and Monitor resolutions have not been tweaked.

Comment: As I've experienced the same bug (and the solution provided here worked for me), let me add a bit extra observations.
The problem started for me, when I was presenting in the conference room, connected to the room conference system. The conference system's monitors became active only when I'd started the presentation mode.
When I'd finished the presentation, I didn't exit the presentation mode, just put the computer to sleep.
After going to my usual setup I'd eventually stopped the presentation mode and from that point the external monitors were active only when in some presentation mode.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Turn on a Powerpoint presentation
2. Press F5 to start slide show
3. Restart computer (without closing the slideshow)
4. See if it works

-V-V

Comment: This is the weirdest bug I've ever had on my computer, and this answer is the solution. Worked perfectly.

Comment: I concur. Apparently it is a repeatable bug (I had precisely the same case) and luckily repeatable solution.

Comment: I had a similar experience and I did exactly this in order to get the monitors working normally again.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I'm using a new Thinkpad 15" 20MAS4EX with a lightning dock on Windows 10 Version 1809 Build 17763.615.

My experience:

1. May 2019 Receive new Thinkpad 15" and Thinkpad lightning dock, 2 4k monitors extending with 2x Mini Displayport from dock...everything working! :)
2. a. June 2019, Mini Displayport stops working. :(
3. b. Switch to HDMI and both monitors work again to extend :)
4. a. July 2019 HDMI stops working on both monitors. :(
5. b. Very sad, same thing had happened on previous Dell laptop and dock. Just use laptop by itself. :(
6. a. August 2019, launch a presentation accidentally with monitors connected via HDMI and both work. :|
7. b. Current state: As long as I launch a PowerPoint Presentation, HDMI works the 2 extended monitors. I can minimize the presentation and use the displays.  ?-:)

Like the original poster, I would love to know why.

[This is my state when I'm not in presentation mode. The monitors are "seen" in Display Settings, but not active or usable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfPfZ.jpg)

[This is what happens when PowerPoint is in Presentation mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT40v.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because you "extend" the displays instead of "duplicate" the displays.

On Windows 10: Setting -> display -> multiple displays -> duplicate these displays.

Then the external displays will show the same contents as those on your laptop/desktop display.